# Should I edit the accepted answer or add a new one?

Tags: discussion, questions

I was just reading [a question about color issues with Windows Image Viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/383681/white-color-is-not-white-in-windows-picture-viewer) and felt like the accepted solution could profit from some [visual guidance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzMHi.png).

Should I edit the accepted answer or add a new answer? I'd like to know how to proceed with this case it particular, but also what the general guideline is.

Answer (score 6):

Since it is the same answer, just adding an image, you should add it as an edit.

If you had more information to add, I would make a new answer, but since it's just a little visual aid, I feel this would be best placed as just an edit. (Remember to upload the image using our image uploader)

Comment: To be honest, I think the answer itself could use some touching up as well (Bibhas explains the solution a lot better). Where is the boundary?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Feel free to post your own answer then - could earn yourself some rep there. If it was identical, then I would say no, but if you have much more to add, then do it.

Comment: I agree. I think the limit is whether or not the original answer got the point across; if there was little effort in explaining what the answer is, then there's no reason for that answer to benefit from edits - it will no longer resemble the original answer. If, however, it got the point across, then edits for details should be the norm